# parameters of Viewport instantiation

Tags: camera, libgdx, viewport

After many tutorials I am still having trouble understanding viewports and how exactly do they relate to cameras.  What exactly do the numbers you put in for example

```
viewport = new ExtendViewport(10,10,camera)
```

actually mean? I was using `ShapeRenderer` and a Texture to see if changing numbers have any effect on how the `Rectangle` moves around. I used keyDown method of InputProcessor with the implementation like this:

```
if(keycode== Input.Keys.X){
            xRect-=10;
        }
```

No matter what the numbers were in viewport instantiation, the Rectangle always moved for the same amount. Also, the Texture was always drawn at the same place at the same aspect ratio. So what does these numbers actually mean?

Comment: Does your ShapeRenderer use the `camera.combined`? And do you do `viewport.update(width, height)` in `resize()`?

Comment: Ah `viewport.update()` was the thing I didn't to. Now I am setting the parameteres to half of those I used for the camera as in: `viewport = new ExtendViewport(cameraWidth/2,cameraHeight/2,camera)`  and it looks like this is just a zoom.

Comment: To generalize, are the numbers used in viewport instantiation similar to how much zoom is applied to camera?

Comment: A `Viewport` manages the camera's viewport size. It makes no sense to use the camera's viewport size as a base to set the camera's viewport size. Please read [the wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports) to learn what viewports do and what the numbers mean.